# What does fetching do in write through cache?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Suppose you have a 32 byte direct mapped cache with 16 bytes per block, and it reads the address 0xd. What are the contents of the cache? I thought the fetcher would add 0xd to the cache in set 1(so second one), byte 6. But in my simulator, 0xc is then a hit, so obviously this is wrong! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For loads, write policy doesn't matter.  It should be the same as a write-through cache.

Comment: 0xd is in the first 16 bytes, so it's in the first set.

Comment: @Peter Cordes yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine which set an address is found in, you use:

```
(addr >> log2(block size)) & (number of sets - 1)
```

(Assumes block size and number of sets are both a power of 2, which they pretty much always are, so `&(n-1)` is the same as `%n`, a modulo)

For your case, it would be: `(0xd >> 4) & 1`, which is 0.

The block in set 0 contains bytes 0x0 through 0xf, so a reference to 0xc is a hit.

The reason why it contains bytes 0x0 through 0xf is that computer memory systems are usually designed to handle *naturally aligned* data more quickly than nonaligned data.   A block of size N is *naturally aligned* if the address which starts the block has zeros in the low log2(N) bits of the address.   So when address 0xd is referenced, the aligned block that contains it (with starting address 0x0) is loaded into the cache.

Comment: The 2nd half of your formula is wrong.  512 sets gives  log2(512) = 9 = `0b1001`.  You actually want `& (sets - 1)`, i.e. modulo the number of sets, for a simple indexing function that uses a contiguous range of address bits (from just above the offset within a block) as the index.

Comment: (Some caches hash the address to determine the set (e.g. L3 cache on current Intel CPUs), to reduce conflict misses when the working set includes many addresses offset from each other by a large power of 2.  (e.g. lots of arrays or functions that are all 2MB aligned, or other accidental situation where that happens.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - Fixed!